# When Web API is called from same project is working fine. But when I call same API from another project in same machine, it is giving 405 method

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

First time when I created Web API project(MVC pattern) and I created few API controllers and called from html page(Ajax call),I am able to call all APIs and get the data.
But second time I've created two separate solutions one is asp.net Web API and another is MVC Web application. 
Now I'm running both the projects in my machine and trying to call web APIs from MVC application, it's coming 405 method not allowed client side error.
Can anyone help me with this scenario.
Anything extra I need to configure in my server Web API to be called from different application?

Comment: Can you provide a code sample where you specify how you call the web application and the declaration of the api endpoint?